# Why my RNN model doesnot give epoch result

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

i have a Simple RNN model with below code:

```
s_input = Input((window_size, ), dtype='int32', name='S')
t_input = Input((window_size, ), dtype='int32', name='T')
emb1 = Embedding(nb_points + 1, emb_size1)
emb2 = Embedding(tm_length + 1, emb_size2)
xe = emb1(s_input) 
he = emb2(t_input)    
x = Concatenate()([xe, he])
x = SimpleRNN(rnn_size)(x)
y = Dense(nb_points, activation='softmax')(x) 
model = Model([s_input, t_input], y)
model.compile('adadelta', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

When i try to use and called the model. I have this model summary:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
S (InputLayer)                  (None, 2)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
T (InputLayer)                  (None, 2)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_32 (Embedding)        (None, 2, 100)       500         S[0][0]                          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_33 (Embedding)        (None, 2, 6)         150         T[0][0]                          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_15 (Concatenate)    (None, 2, 106)       0           embedding_32[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_33[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_10 (SimpleRNN)       (None, 20)           2540        concatenate_15[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 4)            84          simple_rnn_10[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 3,274
Trainable params: 3,274
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

But, it does not give any accuracy and lost result for each epoch. only print something like this:

```
Train on 40 samples, validate on 11 samples
Epoch 1/100
Processing user 1.
```

Is there anyone can help me with this? result for epoch is not printed.

Comment: How exactly are you training the model? That part is not included in your code

Comment: How are fitting the model? What is the steps per epoch used?